# Cross product in distribution analysis

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, distribution-theory

So I have
\begin{equation}
\bar{J_t}(\bar{r},t)=\int d\bar{r}' G(\bar{r},\bar{r}')\left(-\nabla' \times( \nabla' \times \bar{J}(\bar{r}',t))\right) 
\end{equation}
and in a text it says using IBP we can show:
\begin{equation}
\bar{J_t}(\bar{r},t)=- \nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \int d\bar{r}' G(\bar{r},\bar{r}')\bar{J}(\bar{r}',t) \right) 
\end{equation}
provided $\bar{J}$ has compact support. I've done a class in PDE's so I'm familiar with distribution analysis, but we only did such manipulations with the Laplacian, so this is new to me. I was thinking of using the identity,
\begin{equation}
\nabla \times \left( \nabla \times \bar{A} \right) = \nabla \left( \nabla \cdot \bar{A} \right) - \nabla^2\bar{A}
\end{equation}
but I'm not sure. Any advice?

Comment: What do you mean using IBP?

Comment: integration by parts

Comment: Ha. I thought it meant initial boundary problem.

Comment: Also, is $G$ symmetric?

Comment: G is greens function, so $\frac{-1}{4 \pi | \bar{r}-\bar{r}'|}$

Comment: $\nabla' G = -\nabla G$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe
\begin{align}
-\nabla\times\left(\nabla \times \int dr'\ G(r, r')J(r', t)\right) =&\ -\int dr'\ \nabla\times(\nabla\times[G(r, r')J(r', t)])\\
=&\ -\int dr'\ \nabla\times(\nabla G(r, r')\times J(r', t)) \\
=&\ \int dr'\ J(r', t) \Delta G(r, r') -J(r', t)\cdot \nabla^2G(r, r').
\end{align}
Since
\begin{align}
G(r, r') = \frac{-1}{4\pi |r-r'|}
\end{align}
then we see that
\begin{align}
\Delta G(r, r') = \delta(r-r') = \Delta' G(r, r')
\end{align}
and 
\begin{align}
\nabla^2 G(r, r') = \delta(r-r') \mathbf{1}= (\nabla')^2G(r, r').
\end{align}
Hence it follows
\begin{align}
\int& dr'\ J(r', t) \Delta G(r, r') -J(r', t)\cdot \nabla^2G(r, r')\\
 =& \int dr'\ J(r', t) \Delta' G(r, r') -J(r', t)\cdot (\nabla')^2G(r, r')\\
=&\ \int dr'\ \nabla'\cdot J(r', t) \nabla' G(r, r')-\nabla' J(r', t) \cdot \nabla'G(r, r')\\
=&\ \int dr'\ -\nabla'(\nabla'\cdot J(r', t))G(r, r')+(\nabla')^2J(r', t) G(r, r')\\
=&\ \int dr'\ G(r, r')(-\nabla'\times(\nabla' \times J(r', t))).
\end{align}

Comment: thanks - the support condition comes in on the bottom lines when you're 'transferring' the derivatives from G to J?

Comment: Yes. I have assumed the vanishing of $J$ at infinity.